# SQL Exchange Row Values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the exchange seats question from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/exchange-seats/description/).

The teacher wants to change seats for the adjacent students.
Input:

```
+---------+---------+
|    id   | student |
+---------+---------+
|    1    | Abbot   |
|    2    | Doris   |
|    3    | Emerson |
|    4    | Green   |
|    5    | Jeames  |
+---------+---------+
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------+
|    id   | student |
+---------+---------+
|    1    | Doris   |
|    2    | Abbot   |
|    3    | Green   |
|    4    | Emerson |
|    5    | Jeames  |
+---------+---------+
```

Given Solution:

```
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN MOD(id, 2) != 0 AND counts != id THEN id + 1
        WHEN MOD(id, 2) != 0 AND counts = id THEN id
        ELSE id - 1
    END) AS id,
    student
FROM
    seat,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS counts
    FROM
        seat) AS seat_counts
 ORDER BY id ASC;
```

My Solution:

```
select 
(Case 
    when mod(id,2) !=0 and id != count(*) then id + 1
    when mod(id,2) !=0 and id = count(*) then id
    else id - 1
 end) as 'id',
 student
from seat
order by id;
```

The given solution works very well, but mine can only get one row output.

My Output:

```
+---------+---------+
|    id   | student |
+---------+---------+
|    2    | Abbot   |
+---------+---------+
```

Can anyone explain what the difference is between my solution and the given solution and why my solution is wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Can we assume that the IDs are always continuous and that the sequence begins with 1?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes

Answer (score 0):

When using count(*) directly in your query, you will always have one line.
The other solution is using count(*) as a value for the whole query by using a sub query.

Try

```
SELECT id, count(*) FROM seat
```

and

```
SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM seat) FROM seat
```

and observe the difference.